# Converting Time to String like "Just a min ago" is Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Guys I am try to convert Facebook api created time to simply in string ago. This function working well in Google Chrome but not in Firefox.
Firefox always returns `undefined`. Please help me.

```js
var time = "2018-06-01T10:18:49+0000";
var Created_time = timeAgo(time);
console.log(Created_time);

function timeAgo(time) {
  var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g, "/").replace(/[TZ]/g, " ")),
    diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
    day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

  if (isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31)
    return;

  return day_diff == 0 && (
      diff < 60 && "just now" ||
      diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
      diff < 3600 && Math.floor(diff / 60) + " minutes ago" ||
      diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
      diff < 86400 && Math.floor(diff / 3600) + " hours ago") ||
    day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
    day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
    day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil(day_diff / 7) + " weeks ago";
}
```

Actual output should be “Just a min ago” or ”Yesterday” or “7 days ago”.

Comment: you can use momentjs, works great in all browsers

Comment: How can i use that .. please guide me..

Comment: Why are you replacing the correct ISO format to some `/ / /` one? FF supports only some ISO, and your orignal value, without the `replace(...` will work just fine.

Comment: And chrome is more lenient than other browsers with regard to invalid date string formats passed to `Date()`. If you were to `console.log(date)` would see output of "Invalid date" in firefox and probably in a lot of other browsers also

Comment: Thank u @Kaiido , Works well....

Comment: Yes --@charlietfl I agree now...

Comment: Check the link
https://momentjs.com/docs/